# My program doesn't show anything when i run it (approximation of pi in C++)

Tags: c++

As the title suggests i am trying to running the program but it doesn't show anything , no errors nothing
My code so far is :

```
/* based on : pi^2/6 = 1/1^2 + 1/2^2 + 1/3^2 + .... + 1/n^2 */

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  long long i;
  long double sum, fraction, pi;

  sum = 0.0 ;           /* sum reprisents: 1/1^2 + 1/2^2 + 1/3^2 + .... + 1/n^2 */
  i = 1;              /* i as the denominator of the fraction */
  fraction = 1.0;    /* fraction = 1/(((long double) i)*((long double) i)); */

  while (fraction > 1.0e-15);
  {
     sum += fraction;
     fraction = (long double)1 / (((long double) i)*((long double) i));
     i++;
  }  
  pi = sqrt(6*sum);  /* getting pi since currently it's : pi^2/6 = sum */ 
  cout << "pi = " << pi << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Answer below. But what did your compiler warning messages tell you? Any compiler will warn about this probable mistake. You should listen. If you haven't turned on your compilers warnings, then you should find out how to do that, and have them turned on always.

Comment: turn on your compilers warnings and fix them: https://godbolt.org/z/b75b3b. Warnings should be taken as serious as errors (if not more), you just need to help the compiler a bit to report them (eg `-Wall -Werror` is ok for gcc)

Comment: In addition to the mentioned error, I would expect the line `i++` one line before

Answer (score 3):

Your `while` is immediately followed by a semicolon, which makes it spin forever without ever reaching the block where the fraction is updated.

What you wrote parses the same as this:

```
while (fraction > 1.0e-15) {
}

// I'll never reach this block
{
   sum += fraction;
   fraction = (long double)1 / (((long double) i)*((long double) i));
   i++;
}
```

EDIT: this is a good reason to use linters and/or automated code formatters as part of your development, as they make such mistakes evident.

Comment: fwiw no need to use advanced tools. Reading compilers warnings is sufficient (in this case)

Comment: Yes, warning will typically tell you that "something's off" and that's normally sufficient. But I think pairing that with tools like `clang-format` and `clang-tidy` is a great help, especially for people who first wander into C++ and need some hand-holding. If your editor tells you that right away while typing in the code, it makes the mistakes stand out much more obviously.

Comment: Thank you everyone! My program is now running unfortunately it doesn't have the result i hoped for but ill work on that one,